# How do I make ws.append work inside a function

Tags: python, openpyxl

The `ws.append` function doesn't wrinte anything in the excel when is  under the `def add()`. But if I put it outside the `def add()` it works. I tried everything but it's not working and I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```py
    import sys
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    import datetime
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font
    
    
    
    # file creation
    wb = Workbook()
    
    
    
    
    # Window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Aranjamente liste')
    
    # Grid
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 600, height= 300)
    canvas.grid(columnspan = 3, rowspan = 20)
    
    
    # Instrucions
    instruction = tk.Label(root, text = "Scrieti CNP + NUME si PRENUME / CLUB ", font = "Raleway")
    instruction.grid(columnspan = 3, column = 0, row = 0)
    
    
    # CheckBox
    
    ## Variabile
    var1 = IntVar()
    var2 = IntVar()
    var3 = IntVar()
    var4 = IntVar()
    var5 = IntVar()
    var6 = IntVar()
    var7 = IntVar()
    var8 = IntVar()
    var9 = IntVar()
    var10 = IntVar()
    var11 = IntVar()
    var12 = IntVar()
    var13 = IntVar()
    
    # Definesc CheckBox
    kihon_c = Checkbutton( root, text = "Kihon Dousa", variable = var1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda())
    kodachi_c = Checkbutton( root, text = "Kodachi", variable = var2, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda() )
    tatekodachi_c = Checkbutton( root, text = "Tate Kodachi", variable = var3, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda())
    nito_c = Checkbutton( root, text = "Nito", variable = var4, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda())
    chokenFree_c = Checkbutton( root, text = "Choken Free", variable = var5, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda())
    chokenMorote_c = Checkbutton( root, text = "Choken Morote", variable = var6, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda())
    tanto_c = Checkbutton( root, text = "Tanto", variable = var7, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda())
    tateChoken_c = Checkbutton( root, text = "Tate Choken", variable = var8, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda())
    yari_c = Checkbutton( root, text = "Yari", variable = var9, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda())
    bo_c = Checkbutton( root, text = "Bo", variable = var10, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda())
    echipeLupta_c = Checkbutton( root, text = "Echipe Lupta", variable = var11, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda())
    echipeKhion_c = Checkbutton( root, text = "Echipe Kihon Dousa", variable = var12, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda())
    aviz_medical_c = Checkbutton(root, text="Aviz Medical", variable = var13, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, command = lambda:comanda())
    
    # Le aranjez
    kihon_c.grid( columnspan = 1, column = 0, row = 3, sticky=W)
    kodachi_c.grid( columnspan = 1, column = 0, row = 4, sticky=W)
    tatekodachi_c.grid(columnspan = 1, column = 1, row = 3, sticky=W)
    chokenMorote_c.grid(columnspan = 1, column = 1, row = 4, sticky=W)
    chokenFree_c.grid(columnspan = 1, column = 2, row = 3, sticky=W)
    nito_c.grid(columnspan = 1, column = 2, row = 4, sticky=W)
    tanto_c.grid( columnspan = 1, column = 0, row = 5, sticky=W)
    tateChoken_c.grid(columnspan = 1, column = 0, row = 6, sticky=W)
    yari_c.grid( columnspan = 1, column = 1, row = 5, sticky=W)
    bo_c.grid( columnspan = 1, column = 1, row = 6, sticky=W)
    echipeLupta_c.grid( columnspan = 1, column = 2, row = 5, sticky=W)
    echipeKhion_c.grid( columnspan = 1, column = 2, row = 6, sticky=W)
    aviz_medical_c.grid(columnspan = 1, column = 1, row = 7)
    
    
    
    def comanda():
        print(var1.get())
        print(var2.get())
    
    
    # ADD Button
    add_button = tk.Button(root,command = lambda:add(), text = "Adauga", font = "Raleway")
    add_button.grid(columnspan=3,  column= 0, row = 15 )
    
    # Quit Button
    quit_button = tk.Button(root, command = lambda: sys.exit(), text = "Iesire", font = "Raleway")
    quit_button.grid(columnspan = 3, column = 0, row = 20)
    
    
    
    #### AICI BAGI TOATE FUNCTIILE ####
    def add():
        ws1 = wb.active
        ws1.title = "Baieti"
        ws2 = wb.create_sheet("Fete")
    
        nume = text.get(1.14, "2.0-1c")
        cnp = text.get(1.0, 1.13)
        club = text.get(2.0,'end-1c')
        c_cnp = cnp
    
        # Check if the checkboxes are checked
    
        proba1 = "x"
        proba2 = "x"
        proba3 = "x"
        proba4 = "x"
        proba5 = "x"
        proba6 = "x"
        proba7 = "x"
        proba8 = "x"
        proba9 = "x"
        proba10 = "x"
        proba11 = "x"
        proba12 = "x"
        aviz = "Nu are aviz medical"
    
    
        if var1.get() == 1:
            proba1 = "Kihon Dousa"
            print(proba1)
        if var2.get() == 1:
            proba2 = "Kodachi"
            print(proba2)
        if var3.get() == 1:
            proba3 = "Tate Kodachi"
            print(proba3)
        if var4.get() == 1:
            proba4 = "Nito"
            print(proba4)
        if var5.get() == 1:
            proba5 = "Choken Free"
            print(proba5)
        if var6.get() == 1:
            proba6 = "Choken Morote"
            print(proba6)
        if var7.get() == 1:
            proba7 = "Tanto"
            print(proba7)
        if var8.get() == 1:
            proba8 = "Tate Choken"
            print(proba8)
        if var9.get() == 1:
            proba9 = "Yari"
            print(proba9)
        if var10.get() == 1:
            proba10 = "Bo"
            print(proba10)
        if var11.get() == 1:
            proba11 = "Echipe Lupta"
            print(proba11)
        if var12.get() == 1:
            proba12 = "Echipe Kihon Dousa"
            print(proba12)
        if var13.get() == 1:
            aviz = "Are aviz medical"
            print(aviz)
    
    
        varsta = int(c_cnp)/10000000000%100
        x = 1999 + varsta
        ani = 2022 - x
    
        an_nastere = int(c_cnp)/10000000000%100 + 2000
        luna_nastere = int(c_cnp)/100000000%100
        zi_nastere = int(c_cnp)/1000000%100
    
        # Data de nastere comparata cu data de azi
        data_azi = datetime.date.today()
        current_year = datetime.date.today().year
        data_sportiv = datetime.date(current_year, int(luna_nastere), int(zi_nastere))
    
        # Compara data de azi cu data de nastere a sportivului
        if data_sportiv > data_azi:
            ani = ani - 1
    
    
        if cnp.startswith('5') is True:
            ws1.append([cnp])
    
        #elif cnp.startswith('6') == True:
           # ff.write(cnp + "\t" + nume + "\t" + str(int(ani)) + " ani" + "\t" + str(int(zi_nastere)) + "." + str(int(luna_nastere)) + "." + str(int(an_nastere)) + "\t" + str(proba1) + "\t" + str(proba2) + "\t" + str(proba3) + "\t" + str(proba4) + "\t" + str(proba5) + "\t" + str(proba6)
               # + "\t" + str(proba7) + "\t" + str(proba8) + "\t" + str(proba9) + "\t" + str(proba10) + "\t" + str(proba11) + "\t" + str(proba12) + "\n")
    
        # Se sterge dupa adaugare
        text.delete(1.0, END)
        kihon_c.deselect()
        kodachi_c.deselect()
        nito_c.deselect()
        chokenFree_c.deselect()
        chokenMorote_c.deselect()
        tanto_c.deselect()
        tatekodachi_c.deselect()
        tateChoken_c.deselect()
        bo_c.deselect()
        yari_c.deselect()
        echipeKhion_c.deselect()
        echipeLupta_c.deselect()
    
    
    # Text Box
    text = Text(root, width = 40, height = 3, )
    text.insert(INSERT, "")
    text.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=1)
    
    
    
    # Stilizare, arata mai bine
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 600, height= 250)
    canvas.grid(columnspan = 3)
    
    
    ## Mainloop of the window
    wb.save("test.xlsx")
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code and not knowing what "it's not working" means (error? doing something else?) we can't be positive, but it looks like it may be because `ws1` isn't part of the `add()` functions namespace.

Try adding `ws1` as a parameter for `add()` and then including it when you actually call `add()`. Something like this:

```py
#some things, other functions maybe, code blah blah

def add(ws):
    cnp = text.get(1.0,1.13)
    if cnp.startswith('5') is True: # you should also use "is True" instead of "== True", fyi
        ws.append([cnp])

#more code, blah blah
add(ws1)
#blah blah blah
```

Comment: It's not working means that the excel file remains empty and nothing is written

Comment: It`s still not writing in the excel file

Comment: i'd suggest using a debugger and stepping through the code. put a breakpoint on your line `if cnp.startswith('5') is True:` to make sure that that actually is true and it actually goes into the append line.

Comment: yeah, that part is working, the append line isn't working

Comment: are you making any other changes to the workbook that you can confirm are happening and saving?

Comment: I am creating 2 worksheets that are saving and now I am trying to write something in the file

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the `wb.save("test.xlsx")` line had to be put in the `def add(ws1)` because otherwise the excel file didn't save anything.

Comment: glad you were able to find it!